# EDI X12 to JSON parser Python 3.5 available?

Tags: json, parsing, python-3.5, edi, x12

I have a few doubts -

1) How shall I use the existing EDI X12 to XML parser? I'm using Python 3.5.

a) Bots, uses python 2, which shall not support python >= 3.
b) pyx12, there is no documentation, don't know how to use it.
c) Couldn't find any other good parser in open source.

2) If I want to go about building a parser, how should I? I mean, I'm new to python itself, writing a parser algorithm is tad too difficult for me.

Thanks,
Aakash.

Comment: If you can work with text using Python, then you can parse X12.  Personally, you should be spending less time recreating the wheel and more time finding a proper data translator that will scale.  Especially when Bots is exactly what you're looking for, but you're limited by language version?!!?  Or, unless this is a school project.

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend some options:

https://github.com/azoner/pyx12

Pyx12 is a HIPAA X12 document validator and converter. It parses an ANSI X12N data file and validates it against a representation of the Implementation Guidelines for a HIPAA transaction.

---

https://github.com/slott56/TigerShark

TigerShark is an X12 EDI message parser that can be tailored to
a specific partner in the health care payment ecosystem.

---

And here all the documentation needed for bots.

http://bots.sourceforge.net/en/index.shtml

Bots is fully functional software for edi (Electronic Data Interchange)
Note: Use python 2.7; Python >= 3.0 does not work. See Installation documentation.

Comment: is there a way to parse 834 or EDI files ?

Comment: this packages listed I believe have parsers for 834 and other edi types